# DH Elliptic Curves: Why choose a fixed base point?

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, tls

I am having a first look at the TLS key exchange using Diffie Hellman and try to understand the Elliptic Curve variant of it.

So if a client and a server agree on using ECDH for key exchange and they use the *secp256r1* curve, it seems like the base point G is given and they take it from the [standard](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf#page=13) (`04 6B17D1F2 E12C4247 F8BCE6E5 63A440F2 77037D81 2DEB33A0F4A13945 D898C296 4FE342E2 FE1A7F9B 8EE7EB4A 7C0F9E16 2BCE33576B315ECE CBB64068 37BF51F5`)

From my understanding, i could use an arbitrary base point G and obtain a group which i can use for my key-exchange. Whats the advantage of using a fixed one?
Knowing the base point, wouldnt it be possible to create some kind of rainbow-table and thus crack some connections?

To me it seems more intuite that picking a new base point G every time would increase security.
But as far as i understand it, it's not whats done in TLS.
Can anyone tell why we pick a fixed base point instead of generating a new one for each key-exchange?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Knowing the base point, wouldnt it be possible to create some kind of rainbow-table and thus crack some connections?

If you could create such a rainbow table that allows you to compute discrete logs of random values to a base $G$ with nontrivial probability $p$, then you can solve the discrete log to any base (with work that takes an expected $O(1/p)$ time.

Here's how it works:

- You're given the point $H$ and $J$, and want to compute the discrete log of $J$ to base have $H$, that is, the value $x$ s.t. $xH = J$
- First step, compute the discrete log of $H$ to the base $G$, that is, the value $y$ s.t. $yG = H$.  What you do is pick random values $r$, compute $rH$, and use your rainbow table to find try to find the discrete log $y'$ of $rH$.  This takes an expected $1/p$ attempts (because $rH$ is a random point), and one we stumble on an $r$ that works, we have $y = r^{-1}y'$
- Second step, use the same procedure to compute the discrete log $z$ of $J$ to the base $G$; again, this takes an expected $1/p$ attempts.
- Third step is easy; $x = y^{-1}z$; we're done; that works because $yH=G$ hence $H = y^{-1}G$, and $J = zG$, hence $J = z(y^{-1})H$

On the other hand, for any curve we believe is secure, creating such a rainbow table is infeasible; if the order of the curve is $n$, then the creation would take at least $pn$ point multiplications; for all practical purposes, the standard discrete log algorithms that take $O(\sqrt{n})$ time are more feasible.

> Knowing the base point, wouldnt it be possible to create some kind of rainbow-table and thus crack some connections?

In addition to having the same security, it turns out that, if we know $G$ in advance, we can compute $rG$ considerably faster; hence it makes the system faster for the honest parties, and just as secure.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you alluding to pre-computation (NAF) in that final sentence, right?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: there are a lot of various precomputation strategies